# File Upload in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing a MVC 5 application and using MS SQL Server as a database. I have form in this app, which will store the event details in database. in this form i have a file upload field. Actually i want to upload an image in a folder on the server and store its URL in the database so that URL could be used in my front end.

Following is my create action method

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Event_Name,Event_Description,Event_Detail,Image_Url,Event_Date,User_Name,Date_Uploaded,Category_ID")] WASA_Events wASA_Events)
        {
            var filePath = FileUpload();//Function call to get the uploaded file path
            wASA_Events.Image_Url = filePath;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.WASA_Events.Add(wASA_Events);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.Category_ID = new SelectList(db.WASA_Events_Category, "id", "Event_Category", wASA_Events.Category_ID);
            return View(wASA_Events);
        }
```

and FileUpload Function which will return the file path is as under

```
public string FileUpload()
        {
            var filePath = "";
            if(Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[0];
                if(file!=null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/uplods/"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    filePath = path;
                }
            }
            return (filePath);
        }
```

and in my view i used the following

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "WASA_Events", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Now the problem is i got nothing in the Request.Files.Count, means its value is zero. So can't move ahead.

Any Help.

Comment: Is Request.Files.Count 0 in the action?

Comment: Yes, i have checked and it is 0

Answer (score 0):

Check the below.,.,

1. Check whether you can get the files in the request in the Create Action itself. I am sure that the request will maintain state in the FileUpload method too. But check for if it's not.
2. Whether the file upload input is inside the form that you are using in the view ?
3. Whether the file upload input is any third party control ? If so, check if you have the file name is updated in the file upload input in the HTML after selecting the file in the browser.

A little crazy check would be whether you have selected a file and opted to upload the file in the browser.,.,

Answer (score -1):

I just did the file upload by adding the following class

```
public class Pictures
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    }
```

and then use it in my create Controller action method. Below is the code for controller action

```
if (picture.File.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(picture.File.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/assets/uploads/events/"), fileName);
                picture.File.SaveAs(path);
            }
```

and in view

```
<input type="file" id="File" name="File" class="form-control"/>
```

this solvedmy problem